# Unsatisfied Link Error using SwingNode in OpenJFX

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, javafx, openjfx

SwingNode causes Unsatisfied Link Error in application that uses Spring Boot, OpenJFX and Maven

I read through the posts on this,tried to do what they suggested (see my code below) and was not able to resolve my problem.

Can anybody help? Where am I going wrong?

I am running this in IntelliJ using the Maven examples I found.

**DemoApplication**

```java
package com.javafxswingexplore.demo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");

        springContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class);
        fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/primary.fxml"));

        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        springContext.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**FXMLController**

```java
package com.javafxswingexplore.demo;

import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import javax.swing.*;

@Controller
public class FXMLController {

    @FXML
    SwingNode swingNode;

    public void initialize() {

        createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode);
    }

    private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode1) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swingNode1.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**module-info**

```java
module com.javafxswingexplore.demo {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.swing;

    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.context;

    opens com.javafxswingexplore.demo to javafx.fxml, spring.core;
    exports com.javafxswingexplore.demo;
}
```

**pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.javafxswingexplore</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>12</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.javafxswingexplore.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the console output in Intellij:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\java.exe" \
--add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics \
--add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED  --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED\
-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify \
-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain \
-Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true \
"-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=58874:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1\bin" \
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
-p C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\12.0.2\javafx-base-12.0.2-win.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\12.0.2\javafx-graphics-12.0.2-win.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\IdeaProjects\demo\target\classes;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.7.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.1.7.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.7.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.7.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.26\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\12.0.2\javafx-base-12.0.2.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\12.0.2\javafx-graphics-12.0.2.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\12.0.2\javafx-controls-12.0.2.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\12.0.2\javafx-controls-12.0.2-win.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\12.0.2\javafx-fxml-12.0.2.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\12.0.2\javafx-fxml-12.0.2-win.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-swing\12.0.2\javafx-swing-12.0.2.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-swing\12.0.2\javafx-swing-12.0.2-win.jar\
-m com.javafxswingexplore.demo/com.javafxswingexplore.demo.DemoApplication
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.newimpl.SwingNodeInteropN.overrideNativeWindowHandle(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljdk/swing/interop/LightweightFrameWrapper;JLjava/lang/Runnable;)V
    at javafx.swing/com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.newimpl.SwingNodeInteropN.overrideNativeWindowHandle(Native Method)
    at javafx.swing/com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.newimpl.SwingNodeInteropN.overrideNativeWindowHandle(SwingNodeInteropN.java:128)
    at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.notifyNativeHandle(SwingNode.java:320)
    at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.addSceneListeners(SwingNode.java:598)
    at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.doCreatePeer(SwingNode.java:636)
    at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode$2.doCreatePeer(SwingNode.java:137)
    at javafx.swing/com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.SwingNodeHelper.createPeerImpl(SwingNodeHelper.java:65)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.createPeer(NodeHelper.java:94)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.getPeer(Node.java:2600)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doUpdatePeer(Parent.java:177)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doUpdatePeer(Parent.java:109)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.updatePeerImpl(ParentHelper.java:78)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.updatePeerImpl(RegionHelper.java:72)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.updatePeer(NodeHelper.java:102)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.syncPeer(Node.java:710)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.syncAll(Scene.java:2380)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2356)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2512)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:412)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:438)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:562)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:542)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:535)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:341)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

**EDIT: Error Messages**

after setting cache location and javafx.verbose true with
`-Djavafx.cachedir=C:\\Users\\xxx\\Temp\\cache -Djavafx.verbose=true`:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\java.exe" -Djavafx.cachedir=C:\\Users\\xxx\\Temp\\cache -Djavafx.verbose=true --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics ... -m 
com.javafxswingexplore.demo/com.javafxswingexplore.demo.DemoApplication

JavaFX launchApplication method: launchMode=LM_MODULE
WARNING: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\bin\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
...
WARNING: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\bin\msvcp140.dll
Loaded C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\msvcp140.dll from java.library.path
WARNING: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\bin\concrt140.dll
Loaded C:\WINDOWS\system32\concrt140.dll from java.library.path
WARNING: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\bin\prism_d3d.dll
Loaded C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1\jbr\bin\prism_d3d.dll from java.library.path
JavaFX: using com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit
WARNING: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\bin\glass.dll
Loaded C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1\jbr\bin\glass.dll from java.library.path
Calling main(String[]) method

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                        

2019-08-16 17:49:48.830  INFO 29056 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application on DESKTOP-0DQOIUF with PID 29056 (started by xxx in C:\Users\xxx\IdeaProjects\demo)
2019-08-16 17:49:48.832  INFO 29056 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-16 17:49:49.217  INFO 29056 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 0.692 seconds (JVM running for 1.973)
com.sun.javafx.fxml.ModuleHelper : <clinit>
getModuleMethod = public java.lang.Module java.lang.Class.getModule()
getResourceAsStreamMethod = public java.io.InputStream java.lang.Module.getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
thisModule = module javafx.fxml
methodModule = module javafx.graphics
m = public javafx.collections.ObservableList javafx.scene.layout.Pane.getChildren()
WARNING: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\bin\javafx_font.dll
Loaded C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1\jbr\bin\javafx_font.dll from java.library.path
WARNING: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\bin\prism_common.dll
Loaded C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1\jbr\bin\prism_common.dll from java.library.path
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.newimpl.SwingNodeInteropN.overrideNativeWindowHandle(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljdk/swing/interop/LightweightFrameWrapper;JLjava/lang/Runnable;)V
```

Comment: The "missing" native method `overrideNativeWindowHandle`  is in a library named `prism_common.dll`, that goes bundled with `javafx-graphics-12.0.2-win.jar`. And it should work, since you have it included in the module path (with `-p`), in fact your project works for me on Windows and Mac (IntelliJ -> run DemoApplication). Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Thank you for your response, Jose. I have added the stack trace.

Comment: Thx. Can you browse the `javafx-graphics-12.0.2-win.jar` at .m2 for `prism_common.dll`? And if you remove the Swing node, does it work?

Comment: If I comment out this line only :  `swingNode1.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"));` it works. And `prism_common.dll` shows up in the project browser under `C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\12.0.2\javafx-graphics-12.0.2-win.jar!\prism_common.dll` . Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Yes, that was my question. Which JDK 12 are you using? Can you post the result of  running from a terminal `java -version`? Also check if the folder `C:\Users\xxx\.openjfx\cache\12.0.2` has some dlls, including `prism_common.dll`.

Comment: results of running java -version: `openjdk version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)`. The folder `C:\Users\xxx\.openjfx\cache\12.0.2` doesn't exist. Only `C:\Users\xxx\.openjfx\cache\12.0.1` exists, and it doesn't have that dll in it, only 3 others.

Comment: Ok, we are getting there... When I remove the cache folder, and run it again, the cache is created, with 4 dlls. I guess you have an issue accessing that folder (user permissions). Can you try adding to the `init` method: `System.setProperty("javafx.cachedir", "C:\\tmp\\cache");` and run again with SwingNode?

Comment: Adding that line to the init method does not appear to change things (still getting error). Also, when I remove the cache directory, a new one is not created (probably not unexpectedly).

Comment: Do you see at least the dll files added to `C:\tmp\cache`? And do you have write permission on that folder?

Comment: I don't have that folder and it wasn't created. I tried creating a folder C:\Temp\cache, but nothing was created there either.

Comment: Make sure you have read/write access to a folder you can set as cache, and try again? Use also `System.setProperty("javafx.verbose", "true");`. Check if you get any warning in the console while running from IntelliJ.

Comment: I have confirmed I can write to the folder. The warning from Intellij is `com.sun.javafx.fxml.ModuleHelper : <clinit>
getModuleMethod = public java.lang.Module java.lang.Class.getModule()
getResourceAsStreamMethod = public java.io.InputStream java.lang.Module.getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException`

Comment: System.setProperty happens too late. Go to `Run->Edit configurations`, and `Spring Boot -> DemoApplication`, and add these VM options to Environment: `-Djavafx.cachedir=C:\\temp\\cache -Djavafx.verbose=true`. Try again, you should see the messages now in the console.

Comment: Just posted the resulting message as an answer below.

Comment: I see it now: Loaded C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1\jbr\bin\prism_common.dll from java.library.path, the wrong library is loaded from the wrong path!! You need to set -Djava.library.path=C:\temp.

Comment: It's working now. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Great, good to know. I'll post it as an answer, it will surely be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have a Maven project, you are running from IntelliJ (using the Spring Boot plugin). You can see the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\java.exe" \
--add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics \
--add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED  --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED\
-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify \
-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain \
-Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true \
"-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=58874:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1\bin" \
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
-p C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\12.0.2\javafx-base-12.0.2-win.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\12.0.2\javafx-graphics-12.0.2-win.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\IdeaProjects\demo\target\classes;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.7.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;\
...
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\12.0.2\javafx-controls-12.0.2-win.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\12.0.2\javafx-fxml-12.0.2-win.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-swing\12.0.2\javafx-swing-12.0.2.jar;\
C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-swing\12.0.2\javafx-swing-12.0.2-win.jar\
-m com.javafxswingexplore.demo/com.javafxswingexplore.demo.DemoApplication
```

All the modules are resolved from the dependencies of your pom, nonetheless. And the JavaFX dependencies are downloaded from Maven Central.

However, running the project throws:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.newimpl.SwingNodeInteropN.overrideNativeWindowHandle(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljdk/swing/interop/LightweightFrameWrapper;JLjava/lang/Runnable;)V

which means that the native method [overrideNativeWindowHandle](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/320515f469e70bf6ac25f3df2bae307b8ca81161/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/native-prism/SwingInterop.c#L34) is not found in the native library, in this case `prism_common.dll`, that is bundled with `javafx-graphics-12.0.2-win.jar`.

As discussed in the comments, to find out why this was failing we checked first the local cache where the native libraries are stored by default: However `C:\Users\xxx\.openjfx\cache\12.0.2` didn't exist.

Trying to add a different cache folder (with `javafx.cachedir`) didn't work either.

But adding `-Djavafx.verbose=true` helped out by finding out in the console logs *where* the native libraries came from:

> Loaded C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1\jbr\bin\prism_common.dll from java.library.path

IntelliJ was loading `prism_common.dll` from `java.library.path`, that was set in this case to the JetBrains Runtime JBR with path `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1\jbr\lib`.

And probably this [JBR](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/JBR/JetBrains+Runtime) (whether 8 or 11) has a mismatch with the OpenJFX sources, and this is why we get the error listed above.

**Solution**

In this case, the solution is quite easy: don't rely on the JBR libs, but directly on those provided from the OpenJFX dependencies, by setting a different path. For that, just go to Run->Edit configurations, and Spring Boot -> Application, and add this VM option to Environment:

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\temp
```

Save, and run again. Now it should work as expected.